# Sorting alphabetically from file with numerical placeholder

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a list that I need to sort alphabetically, while that is the case I also need to keep their original position as the list is initially listed chronologically.  I've got the list sorting in alphabetic order, I have no idea how to add in the chronological position.

Any ideas?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("prez.dat");
ofstream fout("sorted.dat");

void main()
{
    //fin.open("prez.dat");
    //fout.open("sorted.dat");
    vector<string> names;

    if(!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file..." << endl;
    }

    string word;

    while(getline(fin, word))
        names.push_back(word);

    sort(names.begin(), names.end());

    for (size_t i=0; i <names.size(); i++)
        cout << names[i] << '\n';

    system("pause");

}//End of void main()
```

**EDIT**:  What I'm looking for:

The file looks like this:

Apple
Orange
Banana

What I'm needing is this:
Apple 1
Banana 3
Orange 2

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Show a short example of input files, what your program produces and what it is you'd prefer it to print.

Comment: Edited to show requested info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to keep both the input string and the original ordinal position together in an object.  Then sort based on solely the string portion of the object and then emit both strings and original ordinal position for each object.

For example for your class you could have this:

```
class MyData {
private:
    std::string s;  // the string read from the file
    unsigned ord;   // original position of the string
public:
    // standard constructor
    MyData(std::string str, unsigned order) : s(str), ord(order) {}  
    // this allows you to use "std::cout << md;"
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyData &m) {
        return out << m.s << ' ' << m.ord;
    }
    static bool cmp(const MyData &a, const MyData &b) {
        return a.s < b.s;
    }
};
```

Then all you need is to create and push the objects and to define a comparison operation for use with `std::sort`.  See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) for details and an example of how to do that part.

Here's one way to do that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// MyData code goes here

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: sortfile filename\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::vector<MyData> vec;
    std::string line;
    int i=1;
    for(std::ifstream in(argv[1]); std::getline(in, line); ++i) 
        vec.push_back(MyData(line, i));
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), MyData::cmp);
    std::cout << "vec contains:\n";
    for (auto md : vec)
        std::cout << md << '\n';
}
```

When compiled (as C++11), from this input file which I called `fruit.txt`:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

Using the file `./sorted fruit.txt` gives this result:

```
vec contains:
Apple 1
Banana 3
Orange 2
```

Comment: The problem with using this is that this is all a bit out of my programming grasp, could you possibly comment it up for me?

Comment: I've added a bit more commenting and complete example code.  I'm hoping this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I understand what you exactly want. But I guess you need to know the chronological position for every element in the sorted vector.

If your question is that, the answer is too easy. you can just make a new int victor that has the same length of your victor (10 for example) and contain list of numbers from 1 to the 10. When you sort your victor you have to make changes on your victor. Now just do the same changes on the numbers victor, so you can know the time of each element.

example:

big, car, app
  1,  2,   3

when you sort them they will be like that:

app, big, car
 3,   1,   2

but in this way u cant use this function to sort u must write it by yourself.

Comment: In what way would you suggest I go about sorting it, as your additional vector idea _did_ work to the extent you said it would

Comment: firstly is the example - I mentioned - what u need

Comment: if yes try this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199910/implementing-selection-sort-with-vectors

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports lambda functions, you can use one for the compare:

```
// sort vector by index using lambda compare function

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::string> names;
    std::vector <size_t> index;
    std::string fruits[5] = { "peach", "cherry", "apple", "plum", "banana" };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(fruits) / sizeof(fruits[0]); i++){
        names.push_back(fruits[i]);
        index.push_back(i);
    }

    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&names](size_t i, size_t j)
        {return names[i] < names[j];});

    for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
        std::cout << "names[" << std::setw(2) << index[i] << "] = " <<
                     names[index[i]] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler doesn't support lambda functions, you can sort a vector of iterators to a vector of strings:

```
// sort vector of strings by vector of iterators to vector of strings

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool compare_strings_by_iterator(
        std::vector <std::string>::iterator i,
        std::vector <std::string>::iterator j)
{
    return *i < *j;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::string> names;
    std::vector <std::string>::iterator it;
    std::vector <std::vector <std::string>::iterator> itv;
    std::string fruits[5] = { "peach", "cherry", "apple", "plum", "banana" };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(fruits) / sizeof(fruits[0]); i++)
        names.push_back(fruits[i]);
    for(it = names.begin(); it < names.end(); it++)
        itv.push_back(it);

    std::sort(itv.begin(), itv.end(), compare_strings_by_iterator);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "name [" << std::setw(2) << itv[i] - names.begin() <<
                     "] " << *itv[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```